# Adding and printing items, using lists using python

Tags: python, list, printing, append

So my problem seems quite trivial, but I'm new to python and am writing a simple program that calculates the reactions of a beam. My program does that successfully, but now I want to expand the capabilities to being able to plot the shear and bending moment diagrams along each beam. My thought process is to use a list and add the shear values (for now) to that list, in increments that divides the beam into 100 segments. Afterwards I want to be able to retrieve them and use these values to plot them.

```
class beam:
    def __init__(self, emod, i, length):
        self.emod = emod
        self.i = i
        self.length = length

    def A(self, a, p):  # Calculate reaction at A
        return p * (self.length - a) / self.length

    def B(self, a, p):  # Calculate reaction at B
        return p * a / self.length

    def Mc(self, a, p):  # Calculate moment at C
        return p * a * (self.length - a) / self.length

    def delc(self, a, p):
        return p * a * a * (self.length - a) ** 2 / 3 / self.emod / self.i / self.length

    def delx(self, x, a, p):
        beta = (self.length - a) / self.length
        delta = x / self.length
        return p * self.length * self.length * (self.length - a) * delta * (
                1 - beta * beta - delta * delta) / 6 / self.emod / self.i

    def delx1(self, x, a, p):
        alpha = a / self.length
        delta = x / self.length
        return p * self.length * self.length * a * delta * (
                1 - alpha * alpha - delta * delta) / 6 / self.emod / self.i

    def maxDisplacementCoords(self, a):
        return a * (1.0 / 3 + 2 * (self.length - a) / 3 / a) ** 0.5


class shearValues: # This is the class that adds the shear values to a list
    def __init__(self):
        self.values = []

    def add_values(self, beam, a_val, p):
        j = float(0)
        v = beam.A(a_val, p)
        while j < beam.length:
            if j < a_val:
                continue
            elif j > a_val:
                continue
            elif j == a_val:
                v -= p
            self.values.append(v)
            j += beam.length / float(100)
        v += beam.B(a_val, p)
        self.values.append(v)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    def inertia_x(h, w, t):
        iy1 = w * h * h * h / 12
        iy2 = (w - t) * (h - 2 * t) ** 3 / 12
        return iy1 - 2 * iy2


    beam_list = []
    beam1 = beam(200000000000, inertia_x(0.203, 0.133, 0.025), 5)
    beam2 = beam(200000000000, inertia_x(0.254, 0.146, 0.031), 5)
    beam3 = beam(200000000000, inertia_x(0.305, 0.102, 0.025), 5)
    beam_list.append(beam1)
    beam_list.append(beam2)
    beam_list.append(beam3)

    while True:
        my_beam = beam_list[1]
        beam_choice = input("Which beam would you like to evaluate? 1, 2 or 3 ")
        if beam_choice == '1':
            my_beam = beam_list[0]
        elif beam_choice == '2':
            my_beam = beam_list[1]
        elif beam_choice == '3':
            my_beam = beam_list[2]

        p = float(input("Enter the required load "))
        a_val = float(input("Enter displacement of point load (origin at LHS) "))
        print("Ay = {}".format(my_beam.A(a_val, p)))
        print("By = {}".format(my_beam.B(a_val, p)))
        print("Mc = {}".format(my_beam.Mc(a_val, p)))
        print("Displacement at C = {}".format(my_beam.delc(a_val, p)))
        displacement = input("Do you want to calculate a specific displacement? [Y]es or [N]o ").upper()
        if displacement not in 'YN' or len(displacement) != 1:
            print("Not a valid option")
            continue
        if displacement == 'Y':
            x = float(input("Enter location on beam to calculate displacement (origin on LHS) "))
            if x < a_val:
                print("Displacement at {} = {}".format(x, my_beam.delx(x, a_val, p)))
            elif x > a_val:
                print("Displacement at {} = {}".format(x, my_beam.delx1(my_beam.length - x, a_val, p)))
            elif x == displacement:
                print("Displacement at {} = {}".format(x, my_beam.delc(a_val, p)))
        elif displacement == 'N':
            continue
        print("Max displacement is at {} and is = {}".format(my_beam.maxDisplacementCoords(a_val),
                                                             my_beam.delx(my_beam.maxDisplacementCoords(a_val), a_val,
                                                                          p)))
        # The code doesn't execute the way it is intended from here
        sv = shearValues()
        sv.add_values(my_beam,a_val,p)
```

Currently it seems as if I have created an infinite loop.

As you can see, the code is not optimized at all but any help would be appreciated. And the calculations are correct.

Comment: Can you provide more explanation, and perhaps a drawing of what a beam is, and what you want to draw as end result? Make sure all explanations of your problem is also outside the code (the reader should not understand by code)

Comment: I found a solution by redoing everything, but will do that in the future